# Why is there no TabControl in my VS2017 toolbox

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017

[image]

I'm working on an Asp.Net project - why is there no TabControl in my VS2017 toolbox? Every resource I've searched just assumes that the control is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my research, there is no default tabcontrol in the Toolbox.

You can refer to the following link to know how to create the tabControl in the asp.net webform project.

[Tabcontrol in webform](https://forums.asp.net/t/1502996.aspx?Tabcontrol%20in%20webform)